# If Facebook app is not available I want to open website but priority should be App first

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have 5 different social media platform to open their applications all working good if there is not Instagram, YouTube application it opens web-view but this is not doing the same for Facebook any idea ? How can I resolve this problem.

```
GestureDetector(
                      onTap: _fb,
                      child: Container(
//                          decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.red)),
                        width: 140,
//                          height: 140,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0),
//                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
//                            border: Border.all(color: Colors.red)),

                        child: Image.asset(
                          'imges/fb.png',
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),

_fb() async {
      const url = 'fb://';
      if (await canLaunch(url)) {
        await launch(url);
      } else {
        throw 'Could not launch $url';
      }
    }
```

All other application are working with website URL and they check application first than open web view but same is not happening with Facebook .

Comment: What is the URL that you are using for opening facebook?

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/danishmahmood95

Comment: I think simple URL should work.

Comment: URL working for other platforms but not for Facebook.